# Switching between tabs takes a few seconds

Tags: tabbed-user-interface, performance

Using `gt` and `:tabnext` I need to wait some time and I experience the same lag when I use `:split myfile.txt`.

However `vim myfile.txt` from bash opens much faster.

My Mac is pretty fast, and I don't have too many plugins installed. I use Vim 8 installed with Brew.

Comment: See [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/1841) the lag probably comes from a plugin or a configuration in your vimrc. The question I linked should help you to find out what causes your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started Vim without my vimrc and plugins using
`HOME=/dev/null vim -u NONE myfile.txt`

Works fast. So I need to investigate the plugins and my configuration...

UPDATE: bottleneck was in plugin [tern_for_vim](https://github.com/ternjs/tern_for_vim), I filled the [issue](https://github.com/ternjs/tern_for_vim/issues/189).

Comment: Glad you've tracked down the issue! You should mark this answer as accepted by clicking the tick mark so future readers know the problem has been solved.

Comment: I need to wait two days before I can accept :) this is impossible now

Comment: Ah, sorry! I forgot about the enforced delay.